# Can't boot into windows after removing ubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have deleted the partitions of ubuntu from windows and also wrote the command:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

from the advanced option which appears after holding the shift key while restarting.
But, when I restarted the system, it only showed a Grub terminal mentioning:

> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

Please give some suggestions how can I boot into windows from grub.

Comment: You should have also run the `bootrec.exe /Fixboot` so that a new bootsector can be written to the drive.  That should remove `grub` altogether.

Comment: Now its directly showing a blue screen with 2 options:Troubleshoot and shut down

Comment: @wjandrea,please atleast read the question before tagging it as duplicate!!! I have removed the partitions and now I am stuck,in those solutions,they have mentioned various softwares to remove ubuntu but I can't use them as I can't boot into windows!!

Comment: @ssharma I edited your question, so I did read it. I inferred, and correct me if I'm wrong, you want to boot into Windows normally in the future, without having to write a command in the grub rescue prompt each time.

Comment: @wjandrea,why have you tagged it as duplicate?Just to increase your reputation points?!

Comment: @ssharma Flagging as duplicate does not increase my points. Please keep in mind that I'm trying to help you. I edited my comment above. Maybe that will make my position clearer.

Comment: @wjandrea, But I am getting -1's on my post without any reason.

Comment: +1 because I think its not OK to down vote without given reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only way is to use a self booting CD, like the windows install CD and repair the broken windows boot files. 
Maybe you had the grub2 installed on your Linux partition. In that case your grub is crippled of course. In that case you also could reinstall linux, install grub on the disk and see if windows is booting correctly.

If Windows starts and gives out some error messages, the only way is to use the windows installation CD and its repair option. The Repair must be done several times to be successful. There are many windows sites to explain also more complex ways to repair a windows boot issue if the automatic repair fails. you should google for that.

The post wjandrea linked contains images from the windows repair CD. That what I would try first.